# React: e.target.getAttribute ("id") works 20% of the time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and been trying to fix this for hours. I'm trying to get the id of the button which is clicked But this only gets the id around 20% of the time and the rest it returns nulltext. I have no idea what else to do. I have tried different binding methods but haven't been able to make it work.

I simplified the code here and put it below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
      
class Popupright extends React.Component {

popupnewshow = (e) => {
let ids = e.target.getAttribute("id") + "text";
console.log(ids)
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('poprighttext showtext');
while(elements.length > 0){
  elements[0].classList.remove('showtext');
};
  document.getElementById(ids).classList.toggle("showtext");
};

render() {
  return (
    <div>
       <table className="table-bordered">
         <tbody>
          <tr className="table-samewidth">
            <td className="td-general"><button className="popup" id="xxx" onClick={this.popupnewshow}><div className="popuptitle">xxx</div></button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr className="table-samewidth">
            <td className="td-general"><button className="popup" id="yyy" onClick={this.popupnewshow}><div className="popuptitle">yyy</div></button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr className="table-samewidth">
            <td className="td-general"><button className="popup" id="zzz" onClick={this.popupnewshow}><div className="popuptitle">zzz</div></button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div id="xxxtext" className="poprighttext">
          <p>xxx.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="yyytext" className="poprighttext">
          <p>yyy</p>
      </div>
      <div id="zzztext" className="poprighttext">
          <p>zzz</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
 }
}

export default Popupright;
```

Console Image: The buttons should give the id xxxtext, yyytext or zzztext depending on the button clicked but this only works 20% of the time. The rest it returns nulltext and after some clicks it returns again the proper id:
[image: Console Image: The buttons should give the id xxxtext, yyytext or zzztext depending on the button clicked but this only works 20% of the time. The rest it returns nulltext and after some clicks it returns again the proper id]

Comment: i am not getting your issue. What do you mean 20% of time? Please describe in meaningful way

Comment: Question is, why are you mutating DOM when you are using React?

Comment: We are moving a website that was made in normal html, css and js to react. We want to display different divs depending on the button chosen. I'm afraid I dont know any other way to do it. Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `e.currentTarget.id` should solve your issue.

`e.target` holds the element that you clicked on, but `e.currentTarget` will hold the element where you have bind the handler.

When you use `e.currentTarget`:

```
<button className="popup" id="xxx" onClick={this.popupnewshow}>
   <div className="popuptitle">xxx</div><!-- clicking on here: 
    e.currentTarget.id is xxx -->
</button>
```

When you use `e.target`:

```
<button className="popup" id="xxx" onClick={this.popupnewshow}>
   <div className="popuptitle">xxx</div><!-- clicking on here: 
    there's no id here (the clicked element id) -->
</button>
```

Comment: I added this changes and it returns either the id or empty (returned null before), but it still doesn't get the id all the time.

Comment: I still don't get when someone clicking on button, why do need `currentTarget`.. `.target` should work. A click on `<td>` should do nothing..

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't scroll right.. Didn;t see the div inside the <td>. :) Also `e.persist()` is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

In general better to avoid direct DOM manipulation like `remove`. Also you can get the id directly rather than from the event:

```
const toggleItem = (arrayOfObjects, objectId) => {
  //some implementation of toggle object's vislble prop based on id property in array 
}

class Popupright extends React.Component {

  state = {
    popups: [
      {id: 'xxx', text: 'xxxtext', visible: false},
      {id: 'yyy', text: 'yyytext', visible: false},
      ...
    ]
  }

  togglePopup = id => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      popups: [...toggleItem(prevState.popups, id)]
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        ...
        <td>
          <button onClick={() => this.togglePopup('xxx')} />
        </td>
        ...
      </table>

      <div className="popupsWrap">
        {this.state.popups.map(popup => {
          if (popup.visible) {
            return (
              <div className="poprighttext">{popup.text}</div>
            )
          }
        }}
      </div>
...
```